# How to resolve "Cannot instantiate class: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory" in Java?

Tags: java, tomcat, ejb, websphere

After adding the ejb.jar I am getting this error

```
        javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
```

but if I run this same code in Java console application its getting executed and I am getting the value in my console but when I run this same code by integrating it with my web application it throws a error which I mentioned above.

```
          public  String process(String message, int start) {
          System.out.println("from process method");
          String result = "Unable to Process";
          String ejbClientUrl = DBPropertiesLoader.EJBCLIENT_URL;
            System.out.println("Connecting : " + ejbClientUrl);
          try {

         System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
         System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", DBPropertiesLoader.TI_EJB_URL);


         System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", ejbClientUrl);

         Context ctx = new InitialContext();
         Object ejbObject = ctx.lookup("ejb/EnigmaServiceAccess");
         System.out.println("EJB Object : "+ejbObject);
```

This is my QueryBuilder.java class. I am calling the process method from this class only where I am trying to load my context:

```
    int num = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) {

        try {

            num++;
            count = resultSet.getInt("SNO");

            ArrayList<InvoiceCustomer> list = new ArrayList<InvoiceCustomer>();
            list.add((InvoiceCustomer) bp.toBean(resultSet, InvoiceCustomer.class));

            TFinvdtoHandler tfinv = new TFinvdtoHandler();
            sRequestItems.add(tfinv
                    .createTFinvdtoRequest(list));
            if (num % 1 == 0) {

                xmlToPost = MessageUtil.xmlServiceRequest(
                        sRequestItems, "TFINVNEW");
                logger.debug(xmlToPost);

                System.out
                        .println("**Sending data to TI Plus through EJB Client***"
                                + "\n");
                finalResult = TIPlusEJBClient.process(xmlToPost, count);

                if (!finalResult.equals("Unable to Process")) {

                    List<ServiceResponse> serviceResponses = MessageUtil
                            .processResponse(finalResult);
                    for (ServiceResponse serviceResponse : serviceResponses) {
                        // System.out.println("**Response Status***"
                        // +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus());
                        // System.out.println("**Response CorrID***"
                        // +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus());

                        MigrationUtil.updateMigrationDataStagingStatus(
                                table, serviceResponse
                                        .getResponseHeader()
                                        .getStatus(), serviceResponse
                                        .getResponseHeader()
                                        .getCorrelationId(),
                                serviceResponse.getResponseHeader()
                                        .getDetails().getError()
                                        .toString());
                    }

                }
                logger.debug("\n");
                sRequestItems = new ArrayList<ServiceRequest>();
                finalResult = "Unable to Process";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();

    logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e1.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e1.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e.getMessage());
} finally {

    MigrationUtil.surrenderConnection(connection, resultSet,
            queryStatement);

}

/*
 * System.out.println("Remaining request count ->" +
 * sRequestItems.size()); if (sRequestItems.size() > 0) {
 * 
 * xmlToPost = MessageUtil .xmlServiceRequest(sRequestItems,
 * "TFILCDTO"); logger.debug(xmlToPost); finalResult =
 * TIPlusEJBClient.process(xmlToPost, count);
 * 
 * System.out
 * .println("**Sending remaining data to TI Plus through EJB Client***"
 * + "\n"); if (!finalResult.equals("Unable to Process")) {
 * 
 * List<ServiceResponse> serviceResponses = MessageUtil
 * .processResponse(finalResult); for (ServiceResponse serviceResponse :
 * serviceResponses) { // System.out.println("**Response Status***" //
 * +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus()); //
 * System.out.println("**Response CorrID***" //
 * +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus());
 * 
 * MigrationUtil.updateMigrationDataStagingStatus(table,
 * serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus(),
 * serviceResponse.getResponseHeader() .getCorrelationId(),
 * serviceResponse .getResponseHeader().getDetails()
 * .getError().toString()); }
 * 
 * }
 * 
 * logger.debug("\n");
 * 
 * }
 */

return xmlToPost;
}
```

Comment: The classpath is set differently in the 2 execution scenarios.

Comment: i couldnt get you..kindly explain me quite briefly about the issue

Comment: A `ClassNotFoundException` means the class is not known during execution, that is, not in the classpath. As you can run your code in "java console application" (a) but can't "integrated with your web application" (b), is clear that the classpath is set differently on both cases. Find out which war is contains the missing class and add it to the classpath of the container. This will solve your issue. How to do this depends on your environment.

Comment: i completely understand the issue but wen i added the exact jar "com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar"  i am getting this error please see to below  "INFO: validateJarFile(E:\Eclipse Luna workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ScfUploaddFile\WEB-INF\lib\com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class"